# Listing all files with a .txt extension recursively

Tags: java, file, filefilter

I am trying to recursively search the directory and list all .txt files found. This is my code for it:

```
private static void listFilesForFolder(File folder) throws FileNotFoundException {
for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
        } else {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fileEntry.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                    return pathname.getName().endsWith(".txt");
                }
            })));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using FileFilter to print out all the .txt files but it prints out null instead. Anyone know why that's the case?

Comment: In your code `listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);` is not a recursive call. Because this method you have shown does not take a `File` as a parameter.

Comment: Good catch that was my bad. I edited the post, but the problem still persists. Do you know why?

Comment: What do you believe `fileEntry.listFiles(...)` does when `fileEntry` is **not** a directory, and why do you believe that? --- According to the javadoc: *"If this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, then this **method returns null**"*. That's why it prints null.

Comment: [Walking the file system](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) might be better place to start

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of using a `FileFilter` in the `else` block, you can simply use an `if` statement. Because in this `else` block you always have a file (not a directory). See whether below change works for you.

```
private static void listFilesForFolder(File folder) throws FileNotFoundException
{
  for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
    if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
      listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
    } else {
      if (fileEntry.getPath().toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt")) {
        System.out.println(fileEntry.getPath());
      }
      /*System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fileEntry.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
          return pathname.getName().endsWith(".txt");
        }
      })));*/
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you really want to do this using `FileFilter`, you can do it like this:

```
private static void listFilesForFolder2(File folder) throws FileNotFoundException
{
  File[] textFiles = folder.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
      return pathname.isFile() && pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
    }
  });
  if (textFiles != null) {
    for (File f : textFiles) {
      System.out.println(f.getPath());
    }
  }

  for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
    if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
      listFilesForFolder2(fileEntry);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That’s a great solution! But do you know how to incorporate FileFilter into the function?

Comment: Keep in mind that a file extension can also be in upper letter case.

Comment: @DevilsHnd, thanks. I added `toLowerCase()` to handle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The method `file.listFiles()` return `String[]` only when the `file` object is a `Directory` object,if `file` is a `File` object it will return null. You can just modify you code like this:

```
for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
    if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
        listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
    } else {
        if (fileEntry.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
            System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

if you can use apache commons-io it will be easy to use `IOFileFilter` to filter what you want:

```
    FileUtils.listFiles(folder, new IOFileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return file.getName().endsWith(".txt");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file, String s) {
            return true;
        }
    }, new IOFileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file, String s) {
            return true;
        }
    }).stream().forEach(file -> System.out.println(file.getName()));
```